# SvelteKit and CSS :target selector

Tags: css, sveltekit

I have a basic SvelteKit app with root +layout containing some anchor tags with hash fragments.

```
<nav>
  <a href="/">home</a>
  <a href="/target#10">#10</a>
  <a href="/target#20">#20</a>
  <a href="/target#30">#30</a>
</nav>

<div>
  <slot />
</div
```

In my target route I have +page file containing a bunch of `<p>` tags, all with `id`s and a single CSS rule

```
<p id="1">
  1. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga dicta
  nostrum harum ad? Cumque recusandae deserunt voluptatum eveniet nostrum quod
  sed. Fugit consequatur laboriosam voluptate quidem, velit commodi voluptatum
  perferendis.
</p>
.
.
.
<p id="50">
  50. Dicta harum nulla blanditiis sapiente molestias facere maiores. Quas
  dolore omnis aliquid sapiente vel eius distinctio nulla amet. Ratione velit
  sequi eius eos minima expedita harum consequuntur ab voluptas dolore!
</p>

<style>
  :target {
    background: red;
  }
</style>
```

So, from my home page, when I click on they `#20` link, it navigates to the `target` page with the correct URL (`/target#20`), it scrolls down to the correct position, but the styling is not applied. Only when I click on the `#20` link a second time, does the styling get applied. From here, I can click on `#10` and `#30` and everything works. However, if I go back to the home page and click on a link with a fragment, the styling is missing.

Why does this happen, what am I missing? Any advice would be appreciated.

Full source https://github.com/cenuij/target-styling

Comment: Adding a breakpoint to the main div being modified, it looks like this is the result of ssr and hydration. When the page initially loads, there isn't anything there, so the `:target` selector isn't "set". The way I got around this was by waiting for `onMount`, setting `window.location.hash` to an empty string, then setting it right back to the initial hash. All selectors worked as well as scrolling to that part of the page.